# Media Player Activity in Fragment Not Working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

Below is my **Tab1.java** Code. I am trying to Play a music file in this fragment.
Without implementing `MediaPlayer`, app works just fine on my emulator. But when I insert the `MediaPlayer` lines, even though `Gradle` Builds Successfully, app doesn't open on my simulator and shows Unfortunately App stopped.

```
package com.example.bavarian.sos;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    ImageButton HelpButton ;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


      /*  HelpButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        HelpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer Alarm = MediaPlayer.create(getView().getContext(),R.raw.sound);
                Alarm.start();
            }
        }); */

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    }
}
```

What could be the possible reasons for this Error ?

Comment: What's **getView()** ?

Comment: Can you remove getView() ?

Comment: Method findViewById works fine in **OnCreate** Method. To use this in **OnCreateView**  getView() is required.

Comment: Did you move 
    MediaPlayer Alarm = MediaPlayer.create(getView().getContext(),R.raw.sound);
out of onClick?

Comment: Nope. Uncommenting the above section gives Error on simulator. I am not changing anything.

Comment: My opinion is :getView in MediaPlayer is useless :)

Comment: Tried removing getView from MediaPlayer. Error Remains.

Comment: paste your logcat plz

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `getView().getContext()`  by  `getApplicationContext()`